# Binding value on custom control with TemplateBinding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, templatebinding

I have created a custom control A, with ControlTemplate section, where:

```
<myOtherControl DataContext="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"/>,
```

and MyOtherControl has:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding VMDataProperty}/>
```

In my view I have:

```
<A ItemsSource="{Binding VMData}"/>
```

By my opinion this should work, but it doesn't;

Any thoughts?

Edit:

```
 ViewModelData VMData = new ViewModelData() 
{
    List<Person> VMDataProperty {get; set;}
    string Name { get; set;}
    DateTime DateBuy { get; set;}
    ...
    }
```

Comment: can you post some more detail, what is VMDataProperty, a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you should be setting the DataContext of "A" instead of its ItemsSource.

Comment: this worked:
    <myOtherControl DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"/>, 
    <DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding VMDataProperty}/>
    <A DataContext="{Binding VMData}"/>

Comment: Can you check this as the accepted answer if it worked for you?